# Redirect process output in VB 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I've got a function that works perfectly as long as the output is relatively small. But if the output is long (I think the breaking point is 4150 bytes) the function returns an error and the output is blank. It seems like there is a buffer somewhere that needs to be increased, but I'm not all that familiar with old versions of VB so I'm not sure where to look. Unfortunately I can't upgrade the program to anything other than VB 6.0 so I'm really kinda' stuck here. Any ideas?

```
    Public Function Redirect(szBinaryPath As String, szCommandLn As String) As String
        Dim tSA_CreatePipe              As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrc        As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        Dim tSA_CreateProcessThrd       As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo    As PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Dim tStartupInfo                As STARTUPINFO
        Dim hRead                       As Long
        Dim hWrite                      As Long
        Dim bRead                       As Long
        Dim abytBuff()                  As Byte
        Dim lngResult                   As Long
        Dim szFullCommand               As String
        Dim lngExitCode                 As Long
        Dim lngSizeOf                   As Long
        Dim intReturn                   As Integer

        tSA_CreatePipe.nLength = Len(tSA_CreatePipe)
        tSA_CreatePipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
        tSA_CreatePipe.bInheritHandle = True

        tSA_CreateProcessPrc.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessPrc)
        tSA_CreateProcessThrd.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessThrd)

        If (CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, tSA_CreatePipe, 0&) <> 0&) Then
            tStartupInfo.cb = Len(tStartupInfo)
            GetStartupInfo tStartupInfo

            With tStartupInfo
                .hStdOutput = hWrite
                .hStdError = hWrite
                .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW Or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
                .wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
            End With

            szFullCommand = """" & szBinaryPath & """" & " " & szCommandLn

            lngResult = CreateProcess(0&, szFullCommand, tSA_CreateProcessPrc, tSA_CreateProcessThrd, True, 0&, 0&, vbNullString, tStartupInfo, tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo)

            If (lngResult <> 0&) Then
                lngResult = WaitForSingleObject(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, WAIT_LONG)

                lngSizeOf = GetFileSize(hRead, 0&)
                If (lngSizeOf > 0) Then
                    ReDim abytBuff(lngSizeOf - 1)
                    If ReadFile(hRead, abytBuff(0), UBound(abytBuff) + 1, bRead, ByVal 0&) Then
                        Redirect = StrConv(abytBuff, vbUnicode)
                    End If
                End If
                Call GetExitCodeProcess(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, lngExitCode)
                CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hThread
                CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess

                If (lngExitCode <> 0&) Then Err.Raise vbObject + 1235&, "GetExitCodeProcess", "Non-zero Application exist code"
                CloseHandle hWrite
                CloseHandle hRead
            Else
                Err.Raise vbObject + 1236&, "CreateProcess", "CreateProcess Failed, Code: " & Err.LastDllError
            End If
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Check what `GetFileSize()` and `ReadFile()` are actually returning. If they're returning a value to signify an error, check `Err.LastDLLError` to see what it is.

Comment: GetFileSize = 4151, I'm not sure what you want to see the result of in ReadFile, LastDLLError is 1244. Also, when it's a short output the "WaitForSingleObject" line returns in under a second. But when it's a size that's going to fail it waits until the timeout (currently set to 60 seconds) before continuing. I had it set to an infinite wait, but it did just that. It never returned and I had to shut down the program to kill it.

Comment: When it "waits", has the process you're running exited?

Comment: Good question. If I run the exact same command from a cmd prompt, it finishes within a second or two. So with a 60 second timeout, I'm mostly sure that it has exited.

Comment: I meant in the exact scenario you're trying to debug. Trying something else entirely and being "mostly sure" doesn't really help. The simple fact that `WaitForSingleObject()` is timing out means that the process has not yet exited, maybe as a buffer is full somewhere. I'd like to confirm before I can suggest anything.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. But I'm not sure how to check for the process being done if the Waitfor isn't returning. I mean, that really does say that the process has not finished. But I can't seem to find out why it hasn't. It finishes just fine when run from a cmd prompt so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be finishing properly when there is a bit more data.

Comment: Task manager? Process explorer?

Comment: oh boy ... yeah, the most obvious things to look for. It's confirmed that the called program is not returning an exit code when there is more than some set amount of data. Thanks for helping to point it out. Guess I need to work on debugging the called app.